# Invoking a spring action repeatedly without user interaction

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, jms, spring-3

I Have a requirement like below :

Get invoked a particular action repeatedly without user interaction.For example, I have a message status page which displayed JMS message status.Message status can be changed by a number of application components.What I wanted is, my status UI has to pick latest message status.I need the action which displays status UI to be called repeatedly in an interval of 5 seconds or so, so that UI will get displayed with latest status.

How can I achieve this in spring.Is it something,Polling an action?

Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to ask the server every few seconds using JavaScript and AJAX (pseudo-code using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)):

```
function askServerForStatus() {
    $.getJSON('/your-app/jms-status', function(response) {
        $('#status').text(response.status);
    }
}

setInterval(askServerForStatus, 5000); //every 5 seconds
```

Very simple example, it asks Spring MVC controllers mapped to `/jms-status` and expects the following JSON response:

```
{"status": "Processing..."}
```

Consider using `setTimeout()`.

More general, reliable and robust approach is to use [websockets](/questions/tagged/websockets), [servlet-3.0](/questions/tagged/servlet-3.0) asynchronous support or [comet](/questions/tagged/comet). Also have a look at [atmosphere](/questions/tagged/atmosphere).